How do I switch active network connections by user in Windows?
I have a shared desktop, and want to utilize different LANs based upon the active Windows user.
From the network side, I can accomplish this either by setting the physical active network, or by vLAN tagging all traffic.
What I don't know is what GPO (or better option) can be set such that only particular network connections are available based upon the active user (can't just be at log-in).

You will be unable to select a VLAN based on which user logs into Windows. I don’t even believe you will be able to enable or disable a network adapter that way. What are you trying to isolate exactly by user?

I have two LANs that can either be segregated by physical port or VLAN - I would like some active users to have the LAN that provides full network access and others to have only the restricted LAN

@viper_nugget has Ramhound said this is not possible, what you are looking to do is called GPO with active directory groups, you should take a look at this microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-groups
